# Application Insights: Metadata queries through REST api

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is it possible to submit Application Insights metadata commands via the REST api?  Is the best I can do just what is returned by GET /query/schema?

i.e

.show table requests | project AttributeName...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you asked for is part of the supported query language. For full listing of supported API, you can visit https://dev.applicationinsights.io.

If you need to programmatically query a table's schema you can use:

```
requests | getschema
```

Plugging it to the test tool yields the following request: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&query=%20customEvents%20%7C%20getschema%0A

Alternatively, you can query the whole schema in a single query by using https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/querySchema?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY. This will give you a list of all columns of all tables.

Out of curiosity - why would you want to do it through the REST API?

`

Comment: I'm looking to populate a selectable list of tables which a user can send a query.  Ideally I don't want to hardcode it...
i.e .show tables.
It seems all queries are directly to tables though...

Comment: To answer your question I'm trying to allow a user to create custom metrics with the option to submit them to an AI instance (among other sources).  If there is a better option than the REST API please let me know.

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to query the whole schema (all columns in all tables) in a single request - does that give you the functionality you need?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but your query is the GET query/schema/ call that I mention in the original question.  Currently that is what I am using, but I was wondering if the metadata commands were exposed at all.